# SQL query to retrieve entries if userId matches table1's employee_id or table2's contributor_id

Tags: sql, knex.js

I'm trying to retrieve all kpi_id, kpi_name, employee_id, contributor_id from table1 and table2 if the provided userId matches employee_id from table1 or contributor_id from table2.

Sample table1:

| id | kpi_name | employee_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | kpi1 | 5 |
| 2 | kpi2 | 6 |
| 3 | kpi3 | 9 |

Sample table2:

| id | kpi_id | contributor_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 9 |
| 1 | 3 | 5 |
| 1 | 1 | 6 |

Now, if a given userId is 5 then as this user is the owner of kpi_id 1 and a contributor of kpi_id 3 the result should look like this:

My desired output:

| kpi_id | kpi_name | employee_id | contributor_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | kpi1 | 5 | 5 |
| 3 | kpi3 | 9 | 5 |

So far I've tried the following query:

```
const query = knex.select([
            't1.id as kpiId',
            't1.name as kpiName',
            't1.employee_id as employeeId',
            't2.contributor_id as contributorId'
        ]).from('table1 as t1')
            .leftJoin('table2 as t2', function () {
                this.on('t2.kpi_id', '=', 't1.id')
            })

           query.where({
                't1.employee_id': this._loggedInUser.id,
            }).orWhere(
                't2.contributor_id': this._loggedInUser.id,).orderBy('t1.id');
```

But, this returns duplicate entries if there are multiple contributors of the same kpi_id. My current SQL query generates this:

| kpi_id | kpi_name | employee_id | contributor_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | kpi1 | 5 | 5 |
| 1 | kpi1 | 5 | 6 |
| 3 | kpi3 | 9 | 5 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding distinct and groupBy fixed my issue:

```
const query = knex.select([
            't1.id as kpiId',
            't1.name as kpiName',
            't1.employee_id as employeeId',
            't2.contributor_id as contributorId'
        ]).from('table1 as t1')
            .leftJoin('table2 as t2', function () {
                this.on('t2.kpi_id', '=', 't1.id')
            }).groupBy('t1.id', 't1.name', 't1.employee_id', 't2.contributor_id')

           query.where({
                't1.employee_id': this._loggedInUser.id,
            }).orWhere(
                't2.contributor_id': this._loggedInUser.id,).orderBy('t1.id').distinctOn('t1.id');
```